# Upload file with Nodejs to another server(wamp/nodejs/lamp)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, cross-domain

I'm not asking about uploading a file from a browser to a nodejs script, I found [uploading script here](https://gist.github.com/markdaws/1920625) and its working fine.

But I am looking for the option to upload the file to another server, example I will have a nodejs in server called A,

I want to upload the image to Server called B(where all the image will be)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an HTTP Post request to Server B from Server A that contains the file. If Server B is using Node.JS, you can try [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). It is a seamless middleware for [Express](https://expressjs.com/) that allows file uploading from an HTTP request. Simply, have Server A make an HTTP request containing said file and Server B will save the file or do whatever you like with it.